# passing an object from javascript to controller through jquery post function (web API)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

in my application I have my JS file that reads some info filled in the html page. What I want to do now I passing these info to my controller. So in my script I have:

```
function addNewEmployee() {
    var newEmployeeName = document.getElementById("newEmployeeName").value;
    var newEmployeeSurname = document.getElementById("newEmployeeSurname").value;
    var newEmployeeDateOfBirth = document.getElementById("newEmployeeDateOfBirth").value;
    var newEmployeeRole = document.getElementById("newEmployeeRole").value;
    var newEmployeeEmail = document.getElementById("newEmployeeEmail").value;

    var newEmployee = {
        name : newEmployeeName,
        surname: newEmployeeSurname,
        dateOfBirth: newEmployeeDateOfBirth,
        role: newEmployeeRole,
        email : newEmployeeEmail
    }

    $.post("api/addemployees", {'newEmployee': newEmployee},   function(result) {

    });
}
```

I would like to know if passing an object in this way is correct and then how can I receive it on my controller side:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/addemployees")]
    public bool AddEmployee (Object newEmployee)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Unfortunately by debugging on the controller side I realized that this way is not correct because nothing arrives. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the object like

```
$.post("api/addemployees", JSON.stringify(newEmployee), function(){
})
```

Comment: and I receive it on the server side as? string?

Comment: @Tarta, As `Employee`